# How to format filtered strings and return formated values? Vanilla JS loop

Tags: javascript

I have array:

```
   link https://api/v1/3
   link https://api/v1/3/user-data
   link https://api/v1/3/customer-data
   link https://api/v1/3/suppliers-sup
```

i am filter array :

```
 let res = val.match(/.*\/(.*)/)[1];
```

second way to filter :

```
const result = links.reduce((acc, {href: link}) => {
  const last = link.split('/').pop();
  if (!(last == Number(last))) acc.push(last);
  return acc;
}, []);
```

And right now results is:

```
[
  "user-data",
  "customer-data",
  "suppliers-sup"
]
```

first logic way is with "3" item but no important for now.

What i need ?
to filter to results be:

```
[
  "User data",
  "Customer data",
  "Suppliers sup"
]
```

With first letter big and to remove "-" and apply space

Comment: Show us what you have tried. SO isn't a free code writing service. The objective here is for you to post your attempts to solve your own issue and others help when they don't work as expected. See [ask] and [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

You can format the data like this:

```
// Sample Data
const data = [
  "user-data",
  "customer-data",
  "suppliers-sup"
]

const formattedData = data.map(item => {
  // Seperate words into an array
  let dataItems = item.split("-")

  // Capitalize first letter of each word
  dataItems = dataItems.map(word => word.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + word.slice(1))

  // Join the words back together
  return dataItems.join(" ")
})
```

Answer (score 0):

In a concise manner, you can achieve your result as -

```js
console.log(
  [
    "https://api/v1/3",
    "https://api/v1/3/user-data",
    "https://api/v1/3/customer-data",
    "https://api/v1/3/suppliers-sup"
  ].reduce((acc, href) => {
    let result = href.replace(/.*\/([a-z])?(.*)/,
      (_, $1, $2) => $1 ? $1.toUpperCase() + $2 : "")

    if (result) return [...acc, result]
    return acc
  }, [])
)
```